# IF condition using combination of AND and OR

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'd like to know if my conditions are written with the right way (for the first statement). (in therm of optimization, readability)

```
if(($nb_post_by_user >= 3 && $nb_post_by_user < 5) || ( $nb_post_by_user >= 3 && ($nb_comm_by_user < 15 || $percent_voted < 25) )){

    // Call function A();

}
else if( ($nb_post_by_user >= 5 && $nb_post_by_user < 10) && ($nb_comm_by_user >= 15 && $nb_comm_by_user < 30) && ($percent_voted >= 25 && $percent_voted < 70) ){

    // Call function B();

}
```

Or does the first statement could be written that way? (second statement will be then nested).

```
if($nb_post_by_user >= 3){

    if($nb_comm_by_user >= 15 || $percent_voted >= 25){

        // Call function B

    }
    else{

        // Call function A

    }

}
```

Comment: Second version is easier to read. Computer doesnt care about your formatting. You do it for programmers.

Comment: With fast reading i see that 70 value does not persisnt on second statement.

Comment: They are both correct although the second is easier to read just in case of any typos

Comment: @sectus you are right, i didn't finish the second statement, i'll update it now. But my question is not about if it is working or not but more about which one is preferable and more correct.

Comment: You don't use `$nb_post_by_user < 5` from first statement

Comment: Show equal-logic statements to compare

Comment: I guess @Phantom you are right, i was just scared that my code will not be optimized. I agree from a programmer point of view it is much easier to read the second solution.

Comment: @Brieuc such micro-optimizations doent make much sense for php (for 99% cases). it will be translated to optimized opcode.

Comment: @Phantom It is good to know that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(($nb_post_by_user >= 3 && $nb_post_by_user < 5) || ( $nb_post_by_user >= 3 && ($nb_comm_by_user < 15 || $percent_voted < 25) )){
    // Call function A();
} else if( ($nb_post_by_user >= 5 && $nb_post_by_user < 10) && ($nb_comm_by_user >= 15 && $nb_comm_by_user < 30) && ($percent_voted >= 25 && $percent_voted < 70) ){
    // Call function B();
}

Edited one :


if($nb_post_by_user >= 3) {
    if($nb_post_by_user < 5 || $nb_comm_by_user < 15 || $percent_voted < 25) {
        // Call function A();
    } else if($nb_post_by_user < 10 && $nb_comm_by_user >= 15 && $nb_comm_by_user < 30 && $percent_voted >= 25 && $percent_voted < 70) {
        // Call function B();
    }
}
```

Comment: That seens indeed what i need and i agree the Edited one is much easier to read. I'll use conditions that way from now. Thank you!

Comment: `$nb_post_by_user >= 5` losted

Comment: @sectus, it will come under this condition : `$nb_post_by_user >= 3`

Comment: Yep exactly it will goes just under that one.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion both the statements are not doing the same piece of work. The best logical reason i came up with is this :

The first piece of code will get executed if one of the condition written in the `if` statements are true. But in the second piece of code. The code will always gets executed if the first `if` condition holds true because of the presence of `else` statement instead of `if else`. So   both are doing a different work.

hope it helps :)